# How can I optimize this Python code to better performance?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Is there any way to optimize this code?

```py
def find_duplicates(lst):
    duplicates = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            if lst[i] == lst[j] and lst[i] not in duplicates:
                duplicates.append(lst[i])
    return duplicates
```

The code above is already an improvement of another code, but I think it can be improved

Comment: Explain what this code is supposed to do exactly and provide an input-output sample. There may be completely different approaches possible, depending on what kind of values you want to work with.

Comment: @deceze 
This code will find a list of duplicate IDs coming from multiple JSON files.

Comment: The code in the question is O(N^2), and sorting is O(N log N), but there's an easy O(N) approach - iterate once through the list and keep a count of occurrences of each item, then return those whose count is >1. In fact the Python standard library has `collections.Counter` which will do most of this for you.

Comment: Thank you all so much, it's been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise the collection.Counter class then iterate over its contents to achieve your objective.

The following code identifies items that appear more than once in the list - i.e., not necessarily duplicates

```
from collections import Counter

def find_duplicates(lst):
    return [k for k, v in Counter(lst).items() if v > 1]

print(find_duplicates([1,2,2,3,4,2,3]))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea which does not use an imported library:

```
def find_duplicates(lst):
    duped = set()
    return list(set(x for x in lst if x in duped or duped.add(x)))
```

Note this uses the fact that add() returns None

Example:

```
print(find_duplicates([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3]))
```

gives

```
[3, 4]
```